# Why do I need keyword `this` while using `env` or `param` in DSL closure in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have code based on ["structured DSL"](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-a-more-structured-dsl) concept.

```
// vars/buildStuff.groovy
def call(body) {

    def config = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config
    body()

    node {
        assert env
        assert params
        doStuff()
    }
}
```

In this code I can access `env` and `params` directly, as expected.

However in the top level `Jenkinsfile`:

```
buildStuff {
    someParam=params.SOME_PARAM
    buildId=env.BUILD_ID
}
```

Causes `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'SOME_PARAM' on null object`. I have to work around that by writing this as:

```
buildStuff {
    someParam=this.params.SOME_PARAM
    buildId=this.env.BUILD_ID
}
```

Why is that the case? According to all examples in [Pipelines documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) I should be able to access `env` and `params` directly.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe because of https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-global-variables? global vs object variable?

Comment: have you set parameter like this `properties([parameters([string(name: 'BRANCH', defaultValue: 'master')])])`

Comment: Your question was an answer for me! :D Was getting a NullPointerException while accessing params. Now I know we need to refer it by `this`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an issue with the `resolveStrategy`.

```
def config = [:]
body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
body.delegate = config
```

The `config` you provide resolves any property to its value or null, thus the `owner` is not queried for it. In you example the `owner` is just `this`. That's why it works.

Depending on what you're actually trying to achieve, `OWNER_FIRST` might be a better strategy. If you cannot change this, better use a data structure without defaults for properties.

Comment: The problem statement is the same for me, but changing the strategy to OWNER_FIRST made no difference for me. It's env that I'm specifically interested in.